# no internet with a Realtec RTL 8111/8168B chip set

Tags: networking

I am new to Ubuntu 11.10 in fact have only used Windows.

I am having difficulty getting internet working under Ubuntu.

Hardware - ASUS 24" all in one computer with a Realtec RTL 8111/8168B PCI Express rev 6 chip set.

I have tried to force the IP address through the network manager. The light on the router to green but still could not ping any addresses, and the manager was saying i was connected and had the IP adresses that i forced with ifconfig.

Comment: Hi Larry, it sounds like you've already tried some things. Could you edit your question with a list of things you've changed/attempted? It's possible the problem was originally mundane (eg router needed restart) but you've configured yourself into a hole.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you find and install the r8168 driver from Realtek. The latest version is 8.028.

Answer (score -2):

i had the same problem and i just reinstalled it and everything worked perfectly afterwards, in still new to this operating system but hopefully it works for you, if not switch to the zion os which is free, and closer to windows in look and feel and way easier to use,

Comment: Downvote: Suggesting a very low popularity linux os to a newbie is likely a very bad idea.

Comment: only suggesting the methods  i used, as i stated previously i'm new to to this whole linux thing, but thanks for sharing  javier

Comment: It's nice that you share mindelsewhere, and I'm very happy that zion works for you. But I really believe that suggesting an os with so little resources to a newbie is not a good idea.